# How do you import files in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm facing an issue where I'm trying to split the code up into different files (to make it neater). So far the import is working except for one file.

Currently, my flutter project is setup in this manner
[image]

However, one of my files is not importing correctly.
This is my `chorusSearch.dart` file:
[image]
[image]

[image]

I've tried importing a class from `chorusPage.dart`. But the import is not resolving.
What is wrong here? This is my `chorusPage.dart` file.

[image]

Comment: Your class name is `ChorusPage` and not `_ChorusPage`. Another details you are trying to access methods reserved for `_ChorusPage` this is not the correct way to do this, create a common class and start this method as static to then use the methods where you find best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot call a method or a function of a class that should be instantiated.
You are trying to access a method inside a private class (with the _ char before) of a class that should be initialized before.

If you want to create functions that don't require a view, a page and nothing visual you should make public and static classes and create something like an utility.dart class that contains them.

Then you can call Utility.yourfunction() from where you want

A little example

file utility.dart in lib/utils/

```
void your_method() {
//do something
}
```

then in place you can import the file utility.dart and you can also assign to it a name with "as" like this -> import 'package:appname/utils/utility.dart' as Utility;

then you can use Utility.your_method()